# find string and either add HTML or wrap string in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, search

I'm trying to accomplish the following, preferably using jQuery.

Find `BC-` on a page (it occurs only once).

Then, depending on the page I'm on either:

- add a simple `<br/>` tag before it, or...
- enclose in it in a span tag with a class.

Adding the span would be more complicated because 3 numbers follow the `BC-` ex: `BC-103`.

Comment: do you really have absolutely nothing to go on in regards to where that string is located? There's no parent element that has a dependable class/id?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the regex pattern that will match your string is **BC-\d{3}**

Always remember that string operations like this one are very processor intensive.

Try to use a selector that is fast, like an ID, or tags like P, because both use native JavaScript methods.

The .html() method from jQuery will help you wrap the found content in tags with a little help of Regex (found at [jQuery: replace() or wrap() http://name.tld/request_url?parameter with <a href="this">...</a>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617725/jquery-replace-or-wrap-http-name-tld-request-urlparameter-with-a-href/3617849#3617849)):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("p").each(function () {
        $(this).html(function(i, html) {
            return html.replace(/(BC-\d{3})/g, "<strong>$1</strong>");
        });
    });

});
</script>
<p>BC-X Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
<p>BC-12</p>
<p>BC-123</p>
<p>BC-555 sit amet</p>
```